# JS - Bypass invalid attribute name

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, attributeerror, bypass

I have a strange attribute, `$MyStyleTemplate;placeholder::color="red"`.

When i am using `setAttribute` it causes an error saying that **my attribute name is invalid**.

Is there's a possible way to bypass it?

Comment: Why do you have that attribute when it is not allowed? Can you perhaps NOT have that attribute?

Comment: I would suggest using a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)